# Node.js SendGrid how to attach a PDF

Tags: node.js, pdf, email-attachments, sendgrid

I'm using [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Code_Examples/nodejs.html) to send email in my Node.js application. Every combination I try to attach a pdf ends up with my attached pdf being unreadable.

I've tried:

```
fs.readFile('public_html/img/Report.pdf',function(err,data){
    var base64data = new Buffer(data).toString('base64');

    sendgrid.send({
        to        : hexDecode(_.e),
        from      : 'xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com',
        subject   : 'Report',
        
        files      : [{filename:'Report.pdf',content:'data:application/pdf;base64,'+base64data}],
        // files   : [{filename:'Report.pdf',contentType:'data:application/pdf',url:'public_html/img/'Report.pdf'}],
        // files   : [{filename:'Report.pdf',url:'public_html/img/'Report.pdf'}],
        html       : 'bla bla'
```

does any one know how to prevent 'Failed to load pdf document'??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the README](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs), you should just pass your content, not turn it into a data URI.

```
fs.readFile('public_html/img/Report.pdf', function(err, data) {
    sendgrid.send({
        to        : hexDecode(_.e),
        from      : 'xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com',
        subject   : 'Report',

        files     : [{filename: 'Report.pdf', content: data}],
        html      : 'bla bla'
```

Comment: It only sends 16kb data on file. The rest of them remains same.

Comment: @DharmendraPratapSingh what we can do for that?

Answer (score 7):

With the latest version of the library, it goes like:

```
fs.readFile('public_html/img/Report.pdf', function(err, data) {
    sendgrid.send({
        to          : hexDecode(_.e),
        from        : 'xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com',
        subject     : 'Report',
        attachments : [{filename: 'Report.pdf', 
                       content: data,
                       type: 'application/pdf',
                       disposition: 'attachment',
                       contentId: 'myId'
        }],
        html        : 'bla bla'
```

The field is called "attachments" now.(https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/packages/mail/USE_CASES.md#attachments).

Answer (score 5):

Quite weird, I haven't really checked the docs and such because of answers beforehand already did but this was how I did mine and it worked.

```
function base64_encode(file){
var bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
return new Buffer(bitmap).toString('base64');
}

let data_base64 = base64_encode('../invoice.pdf');

const msg = {
to: emails,
from: '-----.com',
subject: `Invoice`,
text: `Invoice`,
html: "whatever",
attachments: [
  {
    filename: `invoice`,
    content: data_base64,
    type: 'application/pdf',
    disposition: 'attachment'
  }
 ]
};

sgMail
.send(msg)
.then((response) => {
  res.status(200).send('Success');
})
.catch((err) => {
  res.status(500).send(err);
});
```

hope this helps other people.
using @sendgrid/mail": "^6.3.1",